# const_cast conversion to lvalue reference doesn't remove constness

Tags: c++, casting, constants, const-cast

I would like to understand a difference of the below two cases.

```
const uint32_t v0 = 0;
const uint32_t v1 = 1;

const_cast<uint32_t&>(v0) = v1;
std::cout << v0 << std::endl;
```

This results:

> 0

However,

```
struct S {
    const uint32_t v0;
    S() : v0( 0U ) {}
} s;

const_cast<uint32_t&>(s.v0) = v1;
std::cout << s.v0 << std::endl;
```

I get:

> 1

Regarding first case, why does "v0" remain 0?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: There are no wrong answers with undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Applying `const_cast` on data and then modifying it which is *actually constant* has **undefined behavior**. The reason in that *constant* data may be placed in the *readonly* memory by the compiler. So trying to modify it will lead to **UB**, what output will be given depends on compiler.

Also as @Yakk pointed out, compiler may actually use only the value of the *constant variable* to reduce memory usage. In this case, any expression where the constant variable is involved is  edited to replace the variable with actual value, so there is nothing in the memory. And if you try to change memory content, be prepared for **BOOM**.

**Bottom Line:** Don't do this.

Comment: Not just readonly: optimization!  The access to `const` data can be turned into real constants without reading memory